# If $A_1,A_2$ are independent, are $A_1\cap B, A_2\cap B$ independent?

Tags: probability, independence

Let $A_1,A_2$ be independent events. Can we say that $A_1\cap B, A_2\cap B$ are also independent for any other event $B$?

After a few attempts of proving the affirmative, I'm convinced that the answer is negative.

But how should I understand this intuitively? If two events are independent, shouldn't their restrictions to a subspace be independent as well?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you suspect that the statement is false, then come up with a (small) counterexample.

Comment: Try $A_1 = \{1, 2\}, A_2 = \{2, 3\}, B = \{2, 4\}, \Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ with classic probability.

Comment: Or more simply is $B$ if contained in $A_1$ and $A_2$ then the intersections proposed are just $B$ and therefore not independent. So what's making $A_1,A_2$ independent is the part outside $B$.

Comment: Your intuition about restricting independent events to B only works if they are subsets of B or B cuts then just right.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, independence defines a strict relationship of the intersection of two events the to the events themselves. However, we have a lot more latitude in what $A_1 \cap B$ and $A_2\cap B$ can be by different choices of $B$ so there is not *prima facie* reason to think this would hold.

Assuming the above intersections are non-empty, for these to be independent, we need:

$$(*)\;\;\frac{P(A_1\cap A_2 \cap B)}{P(A_2 \cap B)} = P(A_1\cap B),\;\;\forall B $$

Let's define a sequence of subsets of $A_1 \cup A_2$ where we've taken "bites" out of $A_2$ but not $A_1$. Each of these is a possible set $B$ in above and we'll consider the conditional probabilities.

Let $C_1 \subset C_2 \subset C_3 ...$ be an increasing sequence of sets such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} C_i = A_2\setminus A_1$ and  $B_i := A_1 \cup A_2\setminus C_i$. Note that $A_1 \cap B_i = A_1 \cap A_2$ and $A_2 \cap B_i \neq \emptyset\;\;\forall i> 0$

Then

$$P(A_1\cap B_i|A_2\cap B_i) = \frac{P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap B_i)}{P(A_2 \cap B_i)}= \frac{P(A_2 \cap (A_1 \cap B_i))}{P(A_2 \setminus C_i)} = $$
$$\frac{P(A_2 \cap A_1) }{P(A_2 \setminus C_i)}=\frac{P(A_2)P(A_1) }{P(A_2 \setminus C_i)}\text{    (by independence of $A_1$ and $A_2$)}$$

If $(*)$ is true,

$$P(A_1\cap B_i|A_2\cap B_i) = P(A_1\cap B_i)=P(A_1) \;\;\forall i>0$$

However, that requires
$$P(A_2\setminus C_i) = P(A_2) \implies C_i = \emptyset$$

Since $C_i$ is increasing, that means that independence only holds when $B = A_1 \cup A_2$. Otherwise,

$$P(A_2\setminus C_i) < P(A_2) \implies P(A_1\cap B_i|A_2\cap B_i) > P(A_1)\;\quad\square$$

---

### Some additional details

Looking at the limiting behavior as of $B_i$ under the increasing sequence $C_i$ (above) we see

$$\lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{P(A_2 \cap A_1) }{P(A_2 \setminus C_i)} = \frac{P(A_2 \cap A_1) }{P(A_2 \setminus (A_2\setminus A_1))} = \frac{P(A_2 \cap A_1) }{P(A_2 \cap (A_2 \cap A_1^c)^c)}=$$

$$\frac{P(A_2 \cap A_1) }{P(A_2 \cap (A_2^c \cup A_1))} = \frac{P(A_2 \cap A_1) }{P(A_1\cap A_2)} = 1 \neq P(A_1)$$

Similarly, let $D_1 \supset D_2 \supset D_3 ...$ be a decreasing sequence of sets such that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} D_i = \emptyset$ and  $B_i := A_1 \cup A_2\setminus D_i$, then

$$\frac{P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap B_i)}{P(A_2 \cap B_i)} = \frac{P(A_2 \cap A_1) }{P(A_2 \setminus D_i)} \implies$$
$$\lim_{i \to \infty} \frac{P(A_2 \cap A_1) }{P(A_2 \setminus D_i)} = \frac{P(A_2 \cap A_1) }{P(A_2 \setminus \emptyset)} = P(A_1|A_2) = P(A_1)\text{ by independence}$$

Therefore, depending on our choice of $B$, we can make $A_1\cap B$ and $A_2 \cap B$ as dependent or independent as we want.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple counterexample is $B=A_2$. Then $B\cap A_2=A_2$ and $B\cap A_1=A_2\cap A_1$ and clearly $p(A_1\cap B)$ is not independent of $A_2$.